# Would it be a bad idea to send the Shopify access token to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

Once the callback is successful, I get the token that is used for future shop requests.

This is also when I have the merchant create an account with us. So I cannot save the token to their account until they create an account obviously.

is it safe to send the token via EJS from the server to the client side?

Is there a better approach to this I should do also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT send tokens for access to clients. If they approved your App and you have a token, save it and instead, send them a marker along with their account creation codes... so that when they finish that up, you know who they were, and can match the token to them in the future.

Comment: I see, what's the process of sending them a marker called? Any guides on that? Also how would I save it if I have no reference to their account? Because this would be before saving their account. Maybe I could wait on exchanging the temporary code till after they create their account?

Comment: Or maybe I could save it to by db with a reference to their storename, when they make their account, I can match the store name and save it to them. Would that work since I wouldn't be sending the token client side at that point?

Comment: You got it. Sounds like a plan.